# How Do You Properly Configure An Empty View For UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I need to set up a view that fills in the content area of a `UITableView`, and that is displayed whenever that table view is empty, hidden otherwise. That view contains an image, a label, and a button to perform a simple action. I was hoping to achieve two things:

**1)** leverage the `backgroundView` property of `UITableView`, and

**2)** leverage the `storyboard` as much as possible while minimizing the amount of code (maybe use a container view?).

However, I am not sure what is the best way to go about this. Insights appreciated, especially if you have already implemented this solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this a bunch of ways, but the easiest (conceptually) seems to be just use a container view that has two subviews:

- A `UITableView` that is visible when it's not empty.
- A `UIView` that holds your image/label/button that is visible when
  `UITableView` is empty.

Simply change their visibility depending on the content of the `UITableView`

Even if you only use the `UITableView` and set it's `backgroundView` to be the `UIView` to display when the `UITableView` is empty, virtually the same amount of work has to be done (you still have to create both views).

Answer (score 0):

First you want to set your background view in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height)];
//Make this clear and it will be the same as the tableView background color
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
//We can add anything to this text of images
[backgroundView addSubview:imageView];
//This is the important part
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
```

Now to hide or view the background view you need to add a bit of logic to `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` for example:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    //Or wherever your data is
    if([self.data count]>0) {

        self.tableView.backgroundView.hidden=YES;
        return 1;

    }

    else {

        self.tableView.backgroundView.hidden=NO;


    }


    return 0;
}
```

Just check how many sections you have, if you have no sections in the table show the view. If you have sections then hide it.

**Edit**, obviously you could set up a UIView in the interface builder too if you like. Make sure it's the correct dimensions. Load if with something like:

```
UIView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
        loadNibNamed:@"MyView"
        owner:self options:nil]
         firstObject];
```

and again you need to set it: `[self.tableView setBackgroundView:view];`